# Proving power rule for negative integers in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

Prove that the derivative of $\frac{1}{z^n}$ at $z = a$ for any positive integer n and any non-zero complex number $a$ is $−na^{−n−1}$ using complex limits and the
derivative formula for $z^n$.

I will use proof by induction for this problem. First, we will prove the base $n=1$. $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$$ should result in $f'(a)=-a^{-2}$. The complex definition of a derivative states: $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}.$$ So the complex derivative of our $f(z)$ should be $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{z+h}-\frac{1}{z}}{h}.$$ Finding a common denominator and subtracting the fractions in the numerator will result in: $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{z}{z^2+zh}-\frac{z+h}{z^2+zh}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{-h}{z^2+zh}}{h}.$$ Simlifying this fraction gives $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-h}{h(z^2+zh)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-1}{z^2+zh}.$$ Finally, we can set $h=0$ and find that $$f'(z)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-1}{z^2+zh}=\frac{-1}{z^2}$$ and that $f'(a)=-a^{-2}$ so our base case is confirmed.

Now we will try to prove this to be true for the next term $n=k+1$. This gives $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{k+1}}$. Following the limit definition of a derivative $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{(z+h)^{k+1}}-\frac{1}{z^{k+1}}}{h}.$$ Once again simplifying our numerator by subtracting the fractions gives 
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{z^{k+1}}{z^{k+1}(z+h)^{k+1}}-\frac{(z+h)^{k+1}}{z^{k+1}(z+h)^{k+1}}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{z^{k+1}-(z+h)^{k+1}}{z^{k+1}(z+h)^{k+1}}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{z^{k+1}-(z+h)^{k+1}}{hz^{k+1}(z+h)^{k+1}}.$$ Using binomial expansion for $(z+h)^{k+1}=\sum_{q=0}^{k+1}z^{k+1-q}h^{q}$ gives $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{z^{k+1}-\sum_{q=0}^{k+1}z^{k+1-q}h^{q}}{hz^{k+1}(z+h)^{k+1}}.$$ Rewriting the expansion as $\sum_{q=0}^{k+1}z^{k+1-q}h^{q}=z^{k+1}+\sum_{q=1}^{k+1}z^{k+1-q}h^{q}$ allows the $z^{k+1}$ terms to cancel to give $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{z^{k+1}-z^{k+1}-\sum_{q=1}^{k+1}z^{k+1-q}h^{q}}{hz^{k+1}(z+h)^{k+1}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-\sum_{q=1}^{k+1}z^{k+1-q}h^{q}}{hz^{k+1}(z+h)^{k+1}}.$$ From this summation, each term in the numerator will have at least one $h$ term, which allows the $h$ in the denominator to cancel. This gives $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-\sum_{q=1}^{k+1}z^{k+1-q}h^{q-1}}{z^{k+1}(z+h)^{k+1}}.$$

Finally, shifting the summation once again to get $\sum_{q=1}^{k+1}z^{k+1-q}h^{q-1}=z^k+\sum_{q=2}^{k+1}z^{k+1-q}h^{q-1}$ gives $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-(z^k+\sum_{q=2}^{k+1}z^{k+1-q}h^{q-1})}{z^{k+1}(z+h)^{k+1}}.$$ At this point one can plug in $0$ for $h$ into the limit to evaluate it as $$\frac{-z^k}{z^{k+1}z^{k+1}}=\frac{-z^k}{z^{2k+2}}=\frac{-z^k}{z^{2(k+1)}},$$ but I think my proof seems to fall apart here. plugging back in $n=k+1$ gives $$\frac{-z^{n-1}}{z^{2n}}$$ This simplifies to $$\frac{-1}{z^nz}.$$ Which is not what I am trying to solve the limit as. Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your binomial expansion, if written correctly using the same proof leads to the correct expression:
$$\frac{-n}{z z^n}$$

(And you don't actually use induction here)

Comment: I just realized I didn't include the combination of my binomial expansion. Thank you. I think I can continue my proof from here, but what should be used instead of induction?

Comment: The proof is correct, you obtain at the end:
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}=-\frac{n}{z^{n+1}}$$ which is exactly the result you want at the end if I m not mistaken.

Comment: You're not mistaken, but I did have a critical mistake in my proof in my binomial expansion, correcting this gives the result you've posted.